# How to make a try catch recursion in a switch statement iterative?

Tags: c++, exception, recursion, iteration, try-catch

I am trying to make a function that looks like below. I want to make it iterative, but I am not sure since I need to keep all paths open.

```
someFunction( parameters)
{
   //do stuff

   switch( thing )
   case: one
    if (something true)
     { 
         try {  someFunction( different parameters ) } catch(...) { throw }

   case: two

     //if else with the else being a throw exception. 
   case: three

     // same
   case: four 
    ...

   default

return some value
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand very well ur question, but i will try to help!

How to use EXCEPTIONS:

```
...
try
{
if(b == 0)
    throw("A number cannot be devided by zero!\n");
c = a/b
}
catch(string error)
{
      cout << "ERROR: "<< error << endl;
}
return c
...
```

You could use it in a switch statement, after the catch i will return to the case.

```
switch(c)
{
case 0:
    ...
    try { ... throw();}
    catch() { ... error treatment}
    ...
    break;
case 1:
...
}
```

Comment: I understand exceptions a bit, but I am having difficulty on finding a method that is suitable to make this recursive function into an iterative function without removing the exceptions and keeping all paths open during iteration.